# How do objects work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var Ninja = function() {
   this.swingSword = function() {
       return true
   }
}
Ninja.swingFire = function() {
   return true
}

var ninja = new Ninja()
assert(ninja.swingFire()) // undefined
```

So it's creating a new object of Ninja, but why isn't swingFire included in this situation? Could someone explain why?

Comment: Because you have to use `prototype` with classes to add new methods/members `Ninja.prototype.swingFire = function()`. You can only use the direct assignment for object literals

Comment: @devnull69 The OP can use what they have, but they'll have to access it like `Ninja.swingFire()`, which I'm sure they don't want to do (a single, centralized method)

Comment: @devnull69 (I was just replying/referring to your "You can only use the direct assignment for object literals"...that was all...otherwise you're obviously right)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instances created with `new` will inherit from `constructor.prototype`, not from the constructor object itself. This will behave as you want:

```
Ninja.prototype.swingFire = function() {
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Am I right to infer that `this` in `this.swingSword` context refers to the prototype then?

Comment: No, it will refer to the instance. But when you try to access a property and it's not found on the instance, then the prototype chain will be looked up.

Comment: Why else would I want to use `this.swingSword` to attach it to the instance as opposed to using `Ninja.prototype.swingSword`? I know shadowing the prototype function is one.

Comment: Usually, methods go into the prototype, so the same function object is shared by all instances. But sometimes you might want a method to have access to a private variable via closure, then you'll have to create it as an own property of the instance, from the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how objects, functions, "classes" and inheritance in Javascript work, you should take a look at this video:

**The Definitive Guide to Object-Oriented JavaScript:** http://youtu.be/PMfcsYzj-9M

This is the best explanation of object orientation in JS that I have ever seen.

**In your case, the following happens:**

When you create a `new Ninja()`, you create a new empty object (`{}`) with a prototype property that points to the functions's prototype. Then the function *Ninja* will be called as the constructor for your newly created object. It creates the swingSword function and makes it a method of your object.

The *swingFire* function will **not** be assigned to your created object, because it is a method of the function itself, not its prototype. Functions are objects as well, so they can actually have properties.

If an object does not have a certain property or method, it looks at it's prototype. If the prototype has the said property/method, it uses it instead. That means that if you give the prototype a method, every object that uses it can use this method as well. That's why you assign methods to the prototype of a function.

Again: Watch the video and you will understand this explanation.

Comment: The `prototype` property of the constructor is *not* cloned into the instances; the instances just keep a reference to it.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ah, damn, you're right. This stuff just keeps confusing me >_< I corrected it.

Comment: You have confused me even more now..answer is too difficult to understand..I am saying that after using cons-prototypes few times!!!

Comment: @Onaseriousnote That's why I refer to the video explaining everything. Explaining prototypes and inheritance in Javascript is really difficult.